# Puntos equidistante en una recta cualquiera acotadaPython

Tags: python

Quisiera saber si ya existe una función  para hacer algo parecido que np.linspace, pero no en intervalo de escalares sino de vector. Esto es, si tengo 2 puntos y trazo la recta entre ellas como puedo dividirla equidistantemente. Antes de pensarlo quisiera saber si   ya hay algo asi y no lo encuentro. Gracias!!

```
a=[1, 1]
b=[8, 8]
pl.plot(a[0], a[1], 'o', color='red')
pl.plot(b[0],b[1], 'o', color='red')
x=linspace(a[0],b[0])
y=x
pl.plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes dos puntos por los que la recta pasa, siendo el primero `(x0, y0)` y el segundo `(x1, y1)`, entonces la ecuación de la recta es:

```
f(x) = (y1-y0)/(x1-x0)*(x-x0) + y0
```

Es decir, si vamos dando valores a `x` en la ecuación anterior, vamos obteniendo los correspondientes valores de `y`, y cada uno de esos puntos `(x,y)` estarían sobre la recta en cuestión.

Basta por tanto elegir un intervalo del eje X (por ejemplo `[x0, x1]`) y dividir ese intervalo en trozos iguales usando `np.linespace()`. Después, usando la ecuación de la recta, calcular los puntos `y` correspondientes a esos `x`.

El siguiente fragmento ilustra la idea:

```
def f(x, x0, y0, x1, y1):
  """Ecuación de la recta que pasa por (x0, y0) (x1, y1)"""
  return (y1-y0)/(x1-x0)*(x-x0) + y0


# Los dos puntos siguientes serían por los que pasa la recta
a=[1, 1]
b=[8, 5]

# Creamos 5 puntos equidistantes en el eje x
x=np.linspace(a[0],b[0], num= 5)

# Y sus correspondientes imágenes según f(x)
y=f(x, *a, *b)

# Pintamos esos puntos
pl.plot(x,y, 'o', color="red")

# Si quieres, también la recta que los une
pl.plot((a[0], b[0]), (a[1], b[1]))
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]

## Actualización

Después de publicar la respuesta, se me ha ocurrido otra solución mucho más simple, válida para el caso en que el segmento de recta que quieres dividir sea precisamente el que está entre los dos puntos de la recta que conoces. Es decir, precisamente el ejemplo anterior.

En este caso basta dividir el rango `[x0, x1]` en N trozos, y el rango `[y0, y1]` en el mismo número de trozos.

La idea puede implementarse en una función que denominaré `linspace2d()`, que recibirá el punto inicial (una tupla con `(x0,y0)`), el punto final (otra tupla con `(x1,y1)`) y el número de puntos a generar. Devuelve una tupla en la que el primer elemento son las X de los puntos y el segundo son las Y.

```
def linspace2d(start, end, num=10):
  return (np.linspace(start[0], end[0], num=num),
          np.linspace(start[1], end[1], num=num))
a=[1, 1]
b=[8, 5]
x, y = linspace2d(a, b)
pl.plot(x,y, 'o', color="red")
```

[image: Resultado]

La otra versión usando `f(x)` es útil si el segmento que quieres dividir está fuera del intervalo `(x0,y0)`--`(x1,y1)`, o para otros casos en los que tengas la recta definida por un punto y su pendiente, en lugar de dos puntos.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo mi aporte, en mi caso no he utilizado nada más que el módulo `math`:

Cálculo de la distancia y el acimut

```
# Distancia
def distance(a, b):
  xa, ya = a
  xb, yb = b

  return math.sqrt((xb -xa)**2 + (yb - ya)**2)

# Dirección
def azimut(a, b):
  xa, ya = a
  xb, yb = b

  return math.atan2(yb - ya, xb - xa) + (2 * math.pi)
```

Función que tomará los puntos a y b y devolverá los puntos en los que se divide la línea:

```
# Dividir línea
def divideLine(a, b, numPoints):

  if numPoints < 2:
    raise ValueError('n < 2')

  xa, ya = a
  xb, yb = b

  # Obtenemos dirección y distancia
  az = azimut(a, b)
  d = distance(a, b)

  # Dividimos entre distancia entre (numPoints - 1) para obtener
  # el incremento de distancia a usar en cada iteración
  ad = d / (numPoints - 1)

  points = []

  for i in range(numPoints):
    # Obtenemos los incrementos en cada eje
    ax = (ad * i) * math.cos(az)
    ay = (ad * i) * math.sin(az)

    # Coordenadas finales
    x = xa + ax
    y = ya + ay

    points.append([x, y])

  return points
```

**Resultado**

```
a = [0, 0]
b = [8, 8]

print(divideLine(a, b, 3)) ## -> [[0.0, 0.0], [4.000000000000001, 4.0], [8.000000000000002, 8.0]]
```

[**Pruébalo**](https://repl.it/@joseahr/Dividir-linea)

**Muéstralo en una gráfica**

```
a = [-3, 3]
b = [-1, -8]

points = divideLine(a, b, 6)

xs = [x[0] for x in points]
ys = [y[1] for y in points]

pl.plot((a[0], b[0]), (a[1], b[1]))
pl.plot(xs, ys, 'o', color="red")

pl.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]